# How to animate and skip in between?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, keyframes

I apologize if my question didn't make sense, not sure how to word this. So essentially I am creating an animation in a scene but to be placed in a video where it will skip scenes of the character. To create the animation in between is a lot of work for me as I am not much of an animator, how can I skip the places in between without deleting keyframes?

For example, right now I have the character walking down the stairs but the next scene I want to use for my video is the character lying down in the grass (all in the same scene) but how can I skip the part in between where I would have to animate the character walking to the grass? (as it won't be used in my video)

I should also add that I would rather not delete the keyframes / duplicate the character&rig.

Comment: You can create a separate action with the new pose, and use the Nonlinear Animation editor to put it after the first action. Then just move your camera where it is supposed to be for this second action. You can also create a brand new Scene (type > Full Copy), or simply create a new blend file with a save as so that you keep the same objects.

Comment: Thanks again moon boots

Comment: please tell if you meet some obstacles, as I say sometimes it's better to simply create a brand new blend file for a different sequence

Answer (score 0):

Just make the new pose or position keyframes 1 frame away it will be one pose in frame 1 and the new pose in frame 2 you can give the camera a position change of one frame as well. I think that's what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for helping but what I mean is that I also need the character to be in a whole different location haha

Comment: it works the same it doesn't matter. Move the pose and or the location and camera over 1 frame.